# Delphi - Check if a LINKED table exists in Access 2003 DB using ADO

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-7, ado

I have 2 mdb linked. Original.mdb (not to be touched) and a copy.mdb
I've been using this for checking if tables exists:

```
function CheckIfTableExists(myTable : AnsiString): boolean;
var
  x := Integer;
  bTrue : boolean;
begin

f1.ADOConnection1.GetTableNames(f1.ListBox1.Items,False);
bTrue := false;
for x := 0 to f1.ListBox1.Items.Count -1 do
 begin
  if (f1.ListBox1.Items.Strings[x] = myTable) then
   begin
    bTrue := true;
   end;
end;

 if (bTrue = true) then
  begin
   Result := True;
  end
 else
  Result := false;
 end;
end;
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but so far it worked nice for me.
Now I need to check if a LINK to another mdb table exist. Does anyone know how to do that?

I.Bagon

Comment: The final `if` is odd. Why not do `Result := bTrue`? But `bTrue` is not a good name. Just get rid of it and assign directly to `Result`. And don't you want to break out of the look when you find a match?

Comment: Apart from that, case sensitivity will play a role here. If the myTable value differs in casing from the actual table name, it won't get found. Delphi isn't Access. String comparisons in Delphi using `=` are case-sensitive. You would be better of using `if SameText(Value1, Value2) then`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks for the idea. I actually wrote this code to illustrate this line: f1.ADOConnection1.GetTableNames(f1.ListBox1.Items,False); Usually I wouldn't read more than necessary and the name bTrue was just the first thing that popped in mind. I was acctually wandering, if there was a similar way to get the linked table names?

Comment: @MarjanVenema: to be honest I prefer case sensitivity and as I replied to David Heffernan this code was meant to illustrate one key line. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Access MDB file has a hidden table named `MSysObjects` which is basically a list of all objects in the MDB.
You can query this table to find out if an object with a given name exists in the MDB.

`MSysObjects` contains ALL objects in the MDB. Not only tables, but forms and records as well.
You can filter on the `Type` column to get only the tables:

`Type = 1` --> local table
`Type = 6` --> linked table

Comment: You can often get denied access to the system table.

Comment: @ChristianSpecht: Thank you for this idea. I tried it but as Remou wrote, I get denied access to the system table. I tried setting permitions directly in access but the result was the same. Is there a way to get around this problem? I.Bagon

Comment: I think the real question is: Is it possible to access mSysObjects table with Delphi + ADO? I've been searching the net for this answer only to find that people have given up. I guess I'll use try/catch methods for my programme and in the future avoid using Access with Delphi.. Thanks again for your help. I.Bagon